# Existe alguma forma de review de app em flutter para android que seja interna, como o iOS?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Pelo que eu vi, no Flutter ainda nao tem nenhum tipo de revisão dentro do app para Android. Eu procurei em outros locais e vi que para nativo existe essa possibilidade, de pedir uma revisão e basicamente o que acontece é um bottom sheet subindo com o conteúdo da Play Store para fazer a revisão com espaço para colocar as estrelas e o comentário. Como na imagem.
[image: In-App Review]

Comment: Você pode pesquisar com algumas "palavras chaves" sempre que precisar de algum tipo de package no [pub dev](https://pub.dev) [Encontrei esses resultados que podem lhe ajudar.](https://pub.dev/packages?q=review%20app)

Comment: Tem o package "in_app_review": [https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_review](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_review)